# "All Users" Folder

Tags: .net, io

Is there a .NET variable that returns the "All Users" directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use the `system.environment` variables.
Most of the predefined ones are [shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx).

For the "**All Users**" you would use:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSPROFILE")
```

I know I got a lot of upmods and a correct answer for my other stuff, but this actually works. where as the other [environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms933062.aspx) 
I linked to previously don't seem to work with that function call.

Answer (score 1):

Or,

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

You can then pass this result to System.IO.Directory.GetParent() to get the root "All Users" folder.

Comment: beware: on Win7 CommonApplicationData points to C:\ProgramData

Answer (score 1):

Is this any use?

Oops:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774096(VS.85).aspx